# Navigator push same screen multiple times

Tags: dart, flutter, navigation, flutter-navigation, scoped-model

I need push new screen automatic on app startup (if user is login or sign out).

I am use `scoped_model` for auth so need navigate when user value is change in model.

I am follow Brian Egan suggestion here: https://github.com/brianegan/scoped_model/issues/43#issuecomment-442444143

```
class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    ScopedModel.of<AuthModel>(context).addListener(_navigationListener);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    ScopedModel.of<AuthModel>(context)
        .removeListener(_navigationListener);
    super.dispose();
  }


  void _navigationListener() {

switch (ScopedModel.of<AuthModel>(context).AuthStatus) {
  case AuthStatus.NotAuth:
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(‘/Login’);
    break;
  case AuthStatus.Auth:
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(‘/Main’);
    break;
  case AuthStatus.Register:
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(‘/Register’);
    break;

  }
```

`AuthStatus` is `Enum`. I change value in `Model`.

This is push route correct, but have issue:

**Same route is push many times. For example, same Login page is push at least 5 times.**

**How to stop Navigator from push same screen multiple times?**

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Brian Egan's example he had a boolean test in the _navigationListener method. His comment was:

> // This function will be run every time the model changes! We will use it to
>     // check the navigate boolean. If it's set to true, we'll push a new screen!
>     //
>     // If not, we won't do anything.

So, a similar boolean needs to be used in your code to only navigate once despite how many times the method is called.